# What's a good way to split a non-delimited string in Java?

Tags: java, string, split

I want to split strings in the form of EADGBE or DADF#AD into separate strings, each containing either one letter or one letter plus a # sign. Is there any more elegant way than iterating through the string with a brute-force sort of approach?

String.split obviously relies on delimiters, which are then discarded, which is not much use to me at all - for a couple of minutes there I thought `split("[a-gA-G]#?");` was going to work, but no, that doesn't help at all - I almost want the opposite of that...

Comment: Can you give an example of a string that you want to split?

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to go for the brute-force method

Comment: This is trivial. Go for the brute force. Do not add complexity and overviews of a regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Brute force is likely to be your best option, both in terms of code and performance.

Alternatively, you could use a `Matcher`

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[a-gA-G]#?");
Matcher m = p.march(inputString);
List<String> matches = new ArrayList<String>();
while(m.find())
   matches.add(m.group());
```

Comment: Ah, very nice - none of my googling turned up anything about Matchers! Thanks for that. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you forsee changes in pattern you can use:

```
  String s = "DADF#AD"; 
  Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([a-gA-G]#?)");
  Matcher matcher = p.matcher(s);
  while (matcher.find()) {
      System.out.println(matcher.group());
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Using lookahead and lookbehind works:  `String regex = "(?<=.)(?=\\w#?)";`

e.g.,

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Foo {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      String[] tests = {"EADGBE", "DADF#AD"};
      String regex = "(?<=.)(?=\\w#?)";
      for (String test : tests) {
         System.out.println(Arrays.toString(test.split(regex)));
      }
   }
}
```

returns:

[E, A, D, G, B, E]
[D, A, D, F#, A, D]

Comment: `String regex = "(?=(?!^)\\w#?)";`, there you go.

Comment: @refp: that looks to work as well -- preventing the line start from being captured. Slick and thanks!

Comment: Ah... I did not know that was an option! Perhaps not the most human-friendly of techniques - or maybe I really mean novice-friendly - but it's definitely good to be aware that this is something you can do with regexps in Java. Thank you!

Comment: @Oolong: It is the actual solution -- you asked for a regex to use with `String#split(...)`. All the other answers don't fulfill this requirement.

Comment: Not exactly... when I said that I wanted to split a string, I didn't mean I necessarily wanted to `split()` a `String`! I see where you're coming from though.

Answer (score 0):

How about that: add delimiters, then split:

This methods adds delimiters

```
private static String delimit(String in) {
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  for (int i = 0; i < in.length()-1; i++) {
    sb.append(in.charAt(i));
    if (in.charAt(i+1) != '#')
      sb.append(';');
  }
  return sb.toString();
}
```

To use it:

```
String[] notes = delimit("DADF#AD").split(";");
```

Comment: Why not use the for loop to generate a list of tokens rather than building an unnecessary intermediate String?

Comment: @Dunes I've already posted dozens of those standard solutions on SO - just wanted to do something different ;)

Comment: heh! I guess that would work, yes. I did wonder about inserting delimiters, but I figured that there had to be a simpler way... which, as other users have pointed out, there is! But thanks in any case, it's healthy to be aware of alternatives...